# What is the meaning of "entire incident in our rearview mirror"?

Tags: meaning

In heist-comedy movie *Logan Lucky (2017)*, FBI officer said these words to special agents who failed
to catch bank robbers:

> You've had your six months, and you made no arrests. Meanwhile, the
> locals talk about these thieves like  they're some type of Hee Haw
> Heroes. So, we would like to move forward and put this **entire incident
> in our  rearview mirror**, if you will.

What is the meaning of "entire incident in our rearview mirror"?

Comment: Treat the whole incident as something that is in the past, like something you have already driven past in your car.

Comment: Notice that ***if you will*** after using this rather "strange" turn of phrase. That's the speaker's way of acknowledging that he *knows* it's an unusual usage (but at least to *native* Anglophones, the meaning should be obvious even though it's unlikely they'll ever have come across it before).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means to put the entire incident behind you, or to move past it, or to get over it.

It’s figurative.

A car’s [rear view mirror](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rear-view_mirror) is the mirror that’s attached to the windshield that allows the driver to see what’s behind them.

(For some reason, no dictionary I can find contains the non-literal definition, though it isn’t too rare. See also [What does “in the rearview mirror” mean in this context?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/325873/191178).)

Comment: I should think it's pretty obvious why you can't find the metaphorical usage defined in a dictionary. It's not used very often, ***and*** the meaning should be obvious in almost any context where it ***was*** used.